# Is the size of built-in datatypes in c++ managed on source code level?

Tags: c++

When I open `/usr/include/stdint.h` I see things like

```
typedef signed char   int8_t;
```

which means that every `int8_t` is to be treated like `signed char`. This let's me suspect that on my system `signed char` is of size 8bit. (However the other way round would be more intuitive for me i.e. every `signed char` has to be treated like `int8_t`.) Where is the size of `signed char` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

The sizeof fundamental types like `char` (and therefore `signed char`) is defined by your compiler, based on the target system architecture. They're not defined in code.

The typedef above means the opposite - it's defining a new type named `int8_t`, in *terms* of the predefined `char` type. On your system (as on most) `char` is 8 bits wide, so it's the natural way to define an 8-bit integer type.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of the compiler for a particular architecture chooses whatever authors wanted for the "normal" datatype sizes (within the limits). So in a way, it's set in code, but not in the  part visible to your programs in any means.

Then it's formulated in terms of the standard types, so that the sizes match.

Answer (score 0):

It's not.  It's only guaranteed to be at least 8 bits (since it must be able to contain values in the range `[-127, 127]`.  And `int8_t` is also not guaranteed to exist; it's only present on machines where `char` is an 8 bit 2's complement.